# Как массив извлечь из объекта?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Ребята помогите с глупостью в JS. Задекодил JSON в переменную return_arr

```
return_arr = jQuery.parseJSON( ret );
```

Пишу в консоли js return_arr, получаю в ответ:

```
Object
  chart_map: Array[7]
  current_month: 10
  text_month: "Октябре"
  value: "4geo-Сургут"
  __proto__: Object
```

И думаю о чудо, все что мне нужно удачно задекодилось и помещено для меня в объект.
Далее я пишу `return_arr.chart_map` и получаю:

```
return_arr.chart_map
undefined
```

=> как так, как мне тогда массив из объекта вытащить?

Comment: Фигня какая-то.. так не может быть :) Попробуйте просто eval'ом раскодировать свой return_arr. А после неудачной попытки получить chart_map, return_arr всё ещё на месте?

Comment: Если вы задекодели - то `return_arr` это строка!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за отзывы, заенкодилось по кривому как то, поменял php и все заработало

Comment: "что-то не работает? Меняй версию PHP!" :))

Answer (score 0):

попробуй `return_arr = array()` с самого начала.
А потом обращаться как `return_arr[chart_map]`